# How to specify a port number for DNS servers with netplan

Tags: networking, dns, netplan

Ubuntu 20.04 with netplan throws malformed address error when cloudflare dns over tls (1.1.1.1:853) is used. Netplan only excepts 1.1.1.1.

Is there a way to configure DoT or DoH with netplan?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @slangasek pointed out configuring port 853 for an dns entry with netplan is not supported.
`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` is the current way in ubuntu.

```
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1
FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
#Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=no
```

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the error message, netplan does not support specifying a non-default port for DNS servers; it will only use port 53.  I see that systemd-resolved does support non-default ports, so this is a valid feature request for netplan, best reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan.

I have personally never heard before of providers offering DNSSEC on an alternate port.  You might check with your provider if they have a DNSSEC endpoint running on port 53 but a different IP address.

Comment: There is a difference between Dnssec, dns over tls, and dns over https. Dns over tls runs on port 853. DNS over https runs on 443.  DNSsec does not use a port. It adds digital signatures to DNS data. This link explains it https://blog.apnic.net/2018/08/20/dnssec-and-dns-over-tls/